# Dynamically multiply 2 cells and display the result in a third cell using java script

Tags: javascript, html

I am pulling records from a db, displaying them in a table rows with form input fields.  That means there will be multiple rows as seen in the sample html code below. I want to use javascript only. The idea is that when a user enters a quantity, it gets multiplied by the unit price and the result displayed in the sub total field. I am not JS developer, I searched and found the below code which is close to what I need. I will appreciate if someone can make some suggestions so as to get this code work.

```
  <SCRIPT language="JavaScript">
<!--
 function calculate() {
    var Quantity = document.getElementsByName("Quantity").value;
    var unitPrice = document.getElementsByName("unitPrice").value;
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < Quantity.length; i++) {

            total += parseInt(Quantity[i].value) * parseInt(unitPrice[i]);

    }
 document.getElementsByName("subtotal").value = total;

}

 </SCRIPT> 

<table>
 <tr>
<td> 
 <input onblur="calculate()" name="Quantity" size="2" /> 
<input name="unitPrice" value="5" size="2"/>
<input name="subtotal" size="2"/>  
 </td> 
 </tr>

 <tr>
<td> 
 <input onblur="calculate()" name="Quantity" size="2" /> 
<input name="unitPrice" value="5" size="2"/>
<input name="subtotal" size="2"/> 
 </td> 
 </tr>  

</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things: a) `document.getElementsByName("")` returns a NodeList Collection of elements, so you cannot get the value of each input like that, you'll have to get them inside the for loop; b) then you also need to get the value of each `unitPrice[i]` inside the loop before parsing it and c) the total should be reset after each iteration, so can just have it inside the loop. See below:

```js
function calculate() {
  var Quantity = document.getElementsByName("Quantity");
  var unitPrice = document.getElementsByName("unitPrice");
  for (var i = 0; i < Quantity.length; i++) {
    if (!Quantity[i].value) continue; // prevent NaN
    let total = parseInt(Quantity[i].value) * parseInt(unitPrice[i].value);
    document.getElementsByName("subtotal")[i].value = total;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input onblur="calculate()" name="Quantity" size="2" />
      <input name="unitPrice" value="5" size="2" />
      <input name="subtotal" size="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <input onblur="calculate()" name="Quantity" size="2" />
      <input name="unitPrice" value="5" size="2" />
      <input name="subtotal" size="2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In order to avoid getting `NaN` for the result which does not have any value, you can add `if (!Quantity[i].value) continue;` as the first line in the for loop, that should prevent it.